# u-Channel Matrix element for electron-positron annihilation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

This one is a quantum related question. The calculation relates to the Matrix element for the annhilation of a electron-positron into two photons:

$$
e^-e^+\rightarrow\gamma\gamma
$$

I've recently been working on some t-channel calculations of the Matrix element, which I think is:

$$
\mathcal{M}=-\left[\mathcal{E}^{\mu}(p_{3})^{*}\,ie\gamma^{\mu}\,v(p_{1})\right]\frac{(\gamma^{\mu}q_{\mu}+m)}{q^{2}-{m_e^{2}}}\left[\mathcal{E}^{\mu}(p_{4})^{*}\,ie\gamma^{\mu}\,\bar{v}(p_{2})\right]
$$
Using the Feynman rules for QED. As far as I know, this is correct (could someone please advise if this is not?). Rules/notation I am using is:

[image]

Now my question is thus: is the matrix element the same for both the t-Channel and the u-Channel?

Comment: It's similar, but some of the momenta are different. Why don't you just try to do it? And by the way, watch the sign on the denominator of the propagator.

Comment: Excuse the simplification, but is it just a case of swopping $p_3$ and $p_4$ in my expression?

Comment: Probably (can't check right now), but remember that $q$ depends on the $p$.